# Is it possible to import a React Native UI component into a native (Android/iOS) project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

**The goal:** develop a cross-platform design system to import it in any platform (React, React Native, Android, iOS).

**What we got working:** a project, developed in React Native, where some core UI components were develop, to ensure the visuals are consistent among all other projects. This project is imported as a dependency in another React Native app that uses these components successfully. So far so good.

**Where we got stuck:** we wanted to import the same project in native projects (Android and iOS), and use it as custom widgets to build the native UI.

**Knowledge acquired from googling:**

- [This](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-bridge-for-android-and-ios-ui-component-782cb4c0217d) article shows that it is possible to build native components in Java/Swift and use them in a React Native Project. **We would like to do the other way around**.
- There is a SDK called [Diez](https://diez.org/) that works as a transpiler, from Typescript to virtually any language. **It is in early access** and we wouldn't like to depends on a SDK.

**tl;dr**; Is it possible to build a React Native project that serves as a UI component library (i.e. design system) and import it in native Android/iOS projects?

Answer (score 0):

No native project that isn't actively working on going to RN is going to include a react native view-  you're adding tons of memory to load a javascript interpreter and seconds of startup time to start react native for that one view.  And passing data to RN from native is painful (calling native from RN is not, but the reverse path more or less doesn't exist).  If you're going to try to embed RN (and I don't suggest it, pick either pure native or pure RN), it needs to be an isolated piece that doesn't need interaction from the native code.

Comment: Agreed, BUT at least for the project I'm currently working on, the case is just that: a RN project working as a module for two other native (legacy) major projects. So the overhead is already happening.

Comment: Then its possible-  *if* you don't need the native code to interact with it at all.  You would just make each view a ReactView and have its own RN application.  But if you need to send data to it from other parts of the app, or send it commands from native controller code there really is no mechanism for that.

Comment: Yep, I would need this communication. The idea is design a button in React Native, with all stylesheet, and code its behaviour (click method, for example) in the native part.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work.  And if you were to do this with a significant number of components, it would be HUGELY memory intensive-  react views are not cheap.   You might do this for something like a story in a news feed, not for an individual button.